# Newgrp function

Tags: groups

I couldn't exactly understand function of newgrp. Does it helps to move from one group to another group for which particular user is member. Or it allow to become member to group for which the user is not member ,but has group password.     I am not clear about it . Can any of you could give me a clear view about it .

Answer (score 3):

To understand what the `newgrp` command does, you need to understand that when you add a user to a group, the new user won't actually be added to the group, until you log out and log back in again. This is often a hassle because it kills all your programs. `newgrp` allows you to add a user to a group and make it take effect in the current login session.

#### usage

```
# show groups user "ubuntu" belongs to
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ groups ubuntu 
ubuntu : ubuntu adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

# add user "ubuntu" to group: src
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ sudo gpasswd -a ubuntu src
Adding user ubuntu to group src

ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ groups ubuntu
ubuntu : ubuntu adm cdrom sudo dip src plugdev lpadmin sambashare
#                                  ^^^
# user ubuntu is "technically" now added to group `src`

# now try do something that members of `src` can do  
#  i.e. create a file in /usr/local/src/
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ ls -alh /usr/local/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 100 Jul 20 08:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 180 Dec  2 20:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  80 Dec  2 20:15 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   3 Jul 20 08:42 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   3 Jul 20 08:42 games
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   3 Jul 20 08:42 include
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  49 Jul 20 08:45 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 20 08:42 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   3 Jul 20 08:42 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  60 Dec  2 19:53 share
drwxrwxr-x 1 root src   60 Dec  2 19:55 src
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ touch /usr/local/src/a_file
touch: cannot touch '/usr/local/src/a_file': Permission denied
# it doesn't work

# now run "newgrp" on src group
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ newgrp src
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ touch /usr/local/src/a_file

# now you are truly part of src group
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/share/man$ ls -alh /usr/local/src
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 1 root    src      80 Dec  2 21:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    100 Jul 20 08:42 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu  src       0 Dec  2 21:26 a_file
```

Answer (score 1):

`newgrp` runs a shell setting its real group ID (see `man 7 credentials`) to the requested group, which can be either to one of the groups to which the user belongs, or a group of which the user knows the password. (Groups can have passwords just like user accounts.)

To return to the situation before `newgrp` use `exit` to terminate the shell executed by `newgrp`. Because `newgrp` runs a new shell you need to be careful when using it in scripts (hint: pipe a command into it, or use a here-document).

Comment: after reading `man credentials` Im wondering does `newgrp` make a system call to change the group id of the running process ?

Comment: @the_velour_fog: The running process is `newgrp`... . What you mean is why isn't `newgrp` a builtin. It's not a builtin because it must be able to change the group to a group of which the user is not a member; that's why it must be setuid to root.

Comment: ah ok, after running `htop` and `pstree` I understand your point about `newgrp` actually forking an entire new shell! that explains why I had to exit twice when using `newgrp`. Im just testing it now, but Im assuming `newgrp` allows you to temporarily join a group you arent a  part of at all. as you say you only need to know the password to the group ( or a user who belongs to the group)

Comment: my testing is showing that, you need to already belong to the group, before you can switch to it ? not sure if its relevant but I keep getting an error `newgrp: failed to crypt password with previous salt: Invalid argument` if the user doesn't already belong to the group

Comment: You must first assign a password to the group. `The
       user will be denied access if the group password is empty and the user is not listed as a member`.